# How can I get the touch input(positions on the screen) on the Windows Surface Pro when writing the application in c#?

Tags: c#, input, multi-touch, surface

I am very very beginner of C# programming.
The previous program that I made can get touch input as a click event on the Surface Pro.
So, It cannot get multi-touch input.
How can I get the multi-touch inputs(positions on the screen) on the Windows Surface Pro when writing the application in c#?

I heard that I can use touch class, but I never know how to use it ....
I am struggling with this for 2 weeks, but could not make any progress.

Anyone who can explain how to use touch class specifically?
Or any other suggestions to get touch input values from the Surface pro touch panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are programming `WPF`.

Register `UIElement.TouchDown` event, for example, in you MainWindow's constructor, add

```
this.TouchDown += MainWindow_TouchDown;
```

If multiple fingers are touching screen at the same time, the `TouchDown` event is fired for each finger.

You can get the position of the touch (relative to screen) from the `TouchEventArgs` which is passed as an argument to the event handler.

```
void MainWindow_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    TouchPoint pointFromWindow = e.GetTouchPoint(this); //relative to Top-Left corner of Window
    Point locationFromScreen = this.PointToScreen(new Point(pointFromWindow.Position.X, pointFromWindow.Position.Y)); //translate to coordinates relative to Top-Left corner of Screen
}
```

**Note: .NET 4.0 is required, Windows 8 shipped with .NET 4.0 pre-installed. If you are running on Windows 7, you have to ensure it is installed.**

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your comments!
By the way, Using WPF is the only way?
Because I have no experience to implement in WPF environment, are there any other options?

Comment: In `Winform` application, you need to override the `WndProc` and look for WM_TOUCH events. Here is a good example to get the touch point location (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940546(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: How about the Touch class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @KyleDelaney: from the Page you have linked: "The FrameReported event is included in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) to support compatibility with Silverlight. If you do not have to ensure compatibility with Silverlight, use the touch events, such as TouchDown and TouchMove, on UIElement, UIElement3D, or ContentElement. "

Comment: As to Windows Forms and Touch Input: for some reason I did not have the Windows Touch Samples (thanks, kennyzx) installed with the SDK. All the sample projects (including the precious MTScratchpadWMTouchCS for WinForms) can be found at https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples. Hope that helps other WinForms nostalgics like me...